# How to skip remaining steps in a test case 1 and continue with other Test cases in Robot Frame work

Tags: robotframework

```
 *** Test Case ***
 Test Case 1
     step 1
     step 2
     error handling $value
     step 3
     step 4

 Test Case 2
   ....
   ....
   ....

*** Keyword ***
error handling
   Run Keyword if   $value=='Text'
         "execute this steps"              #after matching how to skip remaining steps in test Case 1 and continue with Test Case 2
       ELSE 
           Continue with next steps
```

i want to skip "step3 & step 4" if "$value == Text" in "error handling" keyword

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pass Execution` inside the if clause, if you want to skip the rest.
It does just that, marks the case as passed without running what remains in it (apart from the teardown). And the same can be achieved with failing status by the `Fail` keyword call.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it will not mark status as skip

```
*** Variables ***
${status}=     ${False}

*** Tasks ***
Conditional task: Skip if a response matches
    Skip If    ${status}
    Log to console   Task is skipped

*** Tasks ***
Main task
    Log to console   Task is completed
```

[image]

Try this. It will skip all rest of the steps when condition match

*** Test Case ***

```
Test Case 1
    ${value}=   Set Variable   Text
    ${Text}=    Set Variable    Text
    Log To Console    message1
    Log To Console    message2     
    ${status}=    error handling   ${value}      ${Text}
    BuiltIn.Skip if  '${status}' == '${True}'
    Log To Console    message3    
    Log To Console    message4


*** Keyword ***
    error handling
        [Arguments]    ${value}    ${Text}
        IF     '${value}' == '${Text}'
             Return From Keyword    ${True}
        ELSE 
               Continue with next steps
        END
```

Comment: This will cause the overall status of the case to be "skipped" - effectively the same as not ran.

Comment: My point is - the whole test will be skipped, while OP wants to not execute just certain steps, while the case is tracked as ran (passed). By the way, you don't have to return a value from the keyword, and evaluate it outside - you could have used `Skip` / `Skip If` inside the keyword itself.

Comment: Please use recently added code, it will not mark status as skip. if you set ${status} as ${True} it will skip the rest of the steps